# Error ITMS-90362 -- Share Extension Xcode ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, ionic-framework

I am trying to build an share extension, But during upload i got this error

> Error ITMS -90362"Invalid info.plist value. The Value for the key
>   'NSExtensionActivationRule' in bundle myapp.app/Plugins/myapp.appex is
>   invalid

Comment: What value do you have for that key?

Comment: You should keep the images, they are important to your question.

Comment: Can you expand the key for NSExtension in your Share Extension target? That's where your problem is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting two messages I can see the problem for the second one. The Bundle Version needs to match in both targets. You have Bundle Version set to 0.0.6 in the main target and it's set to 1 in the Extension target. Change that to 0.0.6. "Build Version String, short" doesn't matter.

You'll need to show the values of the NSExtension key in the Extension target to fix the first message.