# iOS App Store Submission with Action Extension receiving ERROR ITMS-90362:

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I'm trying to submit my iOS app with an Action Extension to the App Store, but for some reason I keep receiving this error,

```
ERROR ITMS-90362: "Invalid Info.plist value. The value for the key 'NSExtensionActivationRule' in bundle NAME.app/PlugIns/Counter.appex is invalid. Please refer to the App Extension Programming Guide on https://developer.apple.com"
```

Comment: Just try search for all .plist files in your app, and remove that key?

Comment: @Tj3n Just tried, but still receiving the error

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your current code, attempts and outputs are required for others to assist you. Please see [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to revise your question for better clarity. A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would also be appreciated.

Comment: Did you remove it also in all the bundle and pods?

Comment: @Tj3n yes, I searched the entire project

Comment: Try the answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31001179/error-itms-90362-share-extension-xcode-ios)

Comment: @Tj3n Just did and it worked! Thanks!